# Are asymptotic lower bounds relevant to cryptography?

Tags: cryptanalysis, public-key, complexity

An asymptotic lower bound such as exponential-hardness is generally thought to imply that a problem is "inherently difficult". Encryption that is "inherently difficult" to break is thought to be secure.

However, an asymptotic lower bound does not rule out the possibility that a huge but finite class of problem instances are easy (eg. all instances with size less than $10^{1000}$).

Is there any reason to think that cryptography being based on asymptotic lower bounds would confer any particular level of security? Do security experts consider such possibilities, or are they simply ignored?

An example is the use of trap-door functions based on the decomposition of large numbers into their prime factors. This was at one point thought to be inherently difficult (I think that exponential was the conjecture) but now many believe that there may be a polynomial algorithm (as there is for primality testing). No one seems to care very much about the lack of an exponential lower bound.

I believe that other trap door functions have been proposed that are thought to be NP-hard (see [related question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/356/98)), and some may even have a proven lower bound. My question is more fundamental: does it matter what the asymptotic lower bound is? If not, is the practical security of any cryptographic code at all related to any asymptotic complexity result?

Answer (score 2):

Just because a lower bound has been shown does not necessarily make the problem good for crypto. For example, approximation algorithms or probabilistic algorithms could be used to break the system.

That said, I would imagine that a lower-bound could strengthen the argument for a particular system. So, it would seem that a lower bound is neither necessary nor sufficient, but would have it's benefits.

Comment: So if lower bounds are not the key to security, what makes us think that any particular system is secure (eg RSA)? Are security experts just hoping? I learned about public key cryptosystems in school, but now I don't know why I should have any confidence in them, even if P != NP and factoring is asymptotically hard and etc. etc

Comment: @user19614, The way my first crypto professor put it, a bunch of really smart people have been trying and haven't broken it yet.

Comment: The same was true for Fermat's Last Theorem for 358 years.

Comment: @user19614, oh yes. There is always the chance that someone will develop a fast factoring algorithm or a practical quantum computer tomorrow and the whole world would panic.

Comment: If a quantum computer were to be developed tomorrow, the world would have time to react, shifting to new forms of crypto. If a fast factoring algorithm were developed, there might be no  lead time before it were deployable. In the realm of "anything could happen" the development of a new algorithm is hardly pie in the sky!

Answer (score 0):

The practical security of any cryptosystem ultimately depends on the separation of the complexity classes P and NP. Until that day comes, and let's not hold our breath waiting for someone to prove the P vs NP conjecture  either way, no cryptosystem can be said to be so "complex" as to be unbreakable. For example, say you could show that a certain cryptosystem could be broken by proving that the solution to cracking the algorithm could be reduced to just being able to guess a 256 bit key. Given the laws of physics as we know it and how these laws apply to our current state-of-the-art computer systems, guessing a 256 bit key is considered to be "hard". But how do we know that in some distant galaxy far, far away , there isn't some super-intelligent race that has machines that can guess big keys? We don't and that is why proving that P does not equal NP is so hard to do: you have to show a mathematical proof that there can be no possible shortcut (algorithm) for solving an NP complete problem AND you have to be able to prove that HAL will never be able to guess a 256 bit key with reasonable consistantcy in polynomial time. Good luck!

Comment: The One-Time-Pad is unbreakable.

Comment: @Mikeazo: Hi Mike, did Shannon offer a mathematical proof that the OTP is unbreakable? Could you supply a reference to this, I guess this guy is looking for lower bounds for solving an NP problem (cryptosystem) which is of course equivalent to separating P and NP?

Comment: He did (http://netlab.cs.ucla.edu/wiki/files/shannon1949.pdf). Granted the OTP is not exactly related to the whole NP lower-bound given in the question. I just thought I'd point out that there is a perfectly secure cipher.

Comment: Hi Mike, I just re-read this paper again , read the last two paragraphs on page 704. Shannon never gives a mathematical proof for the security of the OTP, he only talks about the requirements of a perfect secrecy system. He shows that the OTP meets the requirements but he does not offer a mathematical proof (lower bound for the amount of work necessary to break a OTP cipher of length N) of security. Big difference, that is the P vs NP problem.

Comment: There is no reason to bring P=NP into the discussion, or solutions by super-intelligent beings with computers that can guess big keys. Suppose I have a cryptosystem that is proven to be exponentially-hard to break, in the asymptotic sense. Does that characterization have any bearing at all on how secure it is in pratice? I would vote your answer down, but I lack the necessary reputation.

Comment: You're wrong. P vs NP affects every. single. aspect. of cryptography, in theory and in practice. To deny it is to deny the existence of cryptography as a formal system.

Comment: @user19614: Thank you for the virtual down vote; in answer to your question in short: no

Comment: @pg1989, are you saying that if $P=NP$ that cryptography would not exist?

Comment: @Mikeazo: If P=NP there are no secure cryptosystems. Cryptography disappears forever :-(

Comment: @WilliamHird, that seems to contradict [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/12807/5882). I'm not saying you are wrong (could be that that answer is wrong), but I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: : This is an interesting topic but for space reserved for comments let me say I am not an expert on the specific consequences of P=NP in its relationship to cryptography. Read the papers by Russell Impagliazzo, Impagliazzo's Five Worlds or something like that, I don't have the reference handy. He is one of the leading computer scientists in the world hands down, trust him ;)

Comment: @WilliamHird. Just to finish out the discussion here, I thought I'd post a quote from the paper you referenced (very interesting read, btw). "... we shall ignore quantitative issues, such as whether an $n^{100}$ time algorithm for satisfiability would be 'feasible'. We also assume that if an algorithm exists, then it is known to the inhabitants of the world."

Comment: @ Mikeazo: You mean the paper you referenced, :-)OOPs we are being cut off for now. Thanks for the discussion!

Comment: The one-time pad has nothing to do with the P=NP problem. In fact, if you encrypt using a one-time pad, the unicity distance is the length of the text itself, and you can never even brute-force the result out, or even know if you have the right result without other information.

Comment: @JoeZeng: Hi Joe, ALL "unbreakable" cryptosystems are by definition one way functions. Its an open problem in theoretical computer science as to the relationship between one way functions and the P vs NP problem.. If you can prove that the one time pad cryptosystem has nothing to do with hard on average problems in NP, step up and write a paper on it and wait for the announcement of your Turing award.

Comment: @WilliamHird I think you are misunderstanding the nature of a one-way function. Any symmetric encryption algorithm (such as the one-time pad) using the same key to encrypt and decrypt is not a one-way function. A one-way encryption algorithm is a cipher that you cannot decrypt, even given all the information that was used to encrypt it (such as a public-key function).

Comment: @JoeZeng: The one time pad is a one way permutation: you are using a random key and an XOR gate to perform a permutation on the plaintext. A one way permutation is a kind of one way function, read the article in Wiki for one way functions. Also read the paper by Terry Ritter " The Efficient Generation of Cryptographic Confusion Sequences". Go to section 5.1 One Way Functions and see his quote about ALL strong cryptographic systems are essentially one way functions.

Comment: @WilliamHird: In the case of the one time pad, you *don't know* the function that was used to encrypt the data. That's where all its security comes from. A one way function is one where you can know the function and it will *still* be hard to invert.

Comment: @JoeZeng: Joe, I think you might be confused: The strength of the one time pad comes from the randomness of the KEY, not from the "function", the function is just XOR ( or XNOR if you happen to be a natural contrarian) that mixes the plaintext with the key. The key is not the function.

Comment: Ah, but that's where we differ in what we are talking about. The key, along with the encryption "function", creates another "function" specific to that key. If you're familiar with currying, the one-time-pad `f(x, y)` can be curried into `g(x)`, which takes the key `x` and returns the "function" `h(y)` that *I* was referring to, that takes the plaintext `y` and turns it into ciphertext `z`.

Comment: Now, to define `h(y)` without using the key `x` at all *would* theoretically turn it into a one-way function; doing so is a field known as "white-box cryptography". However, in the traditional one-time pad, `h(y)` requires the key `x` to define.

Comment: @JoeZeng: Thanks Joe, we are being kicked out now but thanks for the nice discussion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, asymptotic bounds (depending on some security parameter $n$, often the key size) alone say nothing about the practice, as in practice we do not use $n \to \infty$, but a fixed $n$.

So while these asymptotic bounds on the hardness are nice, quite more usable are bounds for the actually used values. Something like

> Breaking AES with a key size of 128 bit takes at least $2^{100}$ steps of calculation.

is much more useful than something like

> Breaking an AES-like algorithm (defined here) with unlimited key-size $n$ takes (for $n \to \infty$) at least $\Omega(2^{n})$ steps,

as the last one does not say how large one has to make $n$ to attain any security at all, and thus does not say anything about the actually used AES.

For RSA, where different key-sizes are actually usable, we also are quite more interested in bounds (still depending on $n$) which are valid for the values in use.

Comment: Are there results of the kind you describe: concrete lower bound for "steps of calculation" to break AES or RSA? Or are you just saying that would be "more usable" if they did exist?

Comment: For AES, I know of no ones (though there are some results of the form "Attacks by differential|linear cryptanalyis take longer than $2^n$ encryptions" or similar, I think.) For RSA, I think there are only reductions to the RSA asumption (from plaintext recovery) or to factoring the modulus (from key recovery), but I don't know if these deliver any concrete bounds for real-live moduli. So, this is more of a "it would be better if we had those".